# visual studio 2005 32 bit and 64 bit building from command promt

Tags: visual-studio, command-line-arguments

I want to build a project automatically from command prompt. I am using Visual Studio 2005. I want to build for x86 and x64 platforms. I tried running `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe" myproject.sln /Build "Release|x86"` but its not working.

Comment: Use the Visual Studio Command Prompt shortcut so everything is setup correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Use `"Release|Win32"` and `"Release|x64"`.